# move from fragment to an activity in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, android-activity, xamarin, fragment

I am working with xamarin andorid Application.In my application I have some fragments and activitis.How to move from aone fragment to an activity?I have tried **StartActivity(typeof(TargetActivity))** but it says ,cannot implicitly convert type 'Type' to Intent.
I also tried this

```
var intent = new Intent(this,typeof(TargetActivity));
StartActivity(intent);
```

but i got an erro :

```
Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'Android.Content.Intent.Intent(Android.Content.Context, System.Type)' has some invalid arguments (CS1502) (AndroidApplication)

Error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'AndroidApplication.DrawerMenuFragment' to 'Android.Content.Context' (CS1503) (AndroidApplication)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is you do this from Fragment you have to use `Activity` instead of `this` as your first argument like so:

```
var intent = new Intent(Activity,typeof(TargetActivity));
StartActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Move from one fragment to an activity?

var intent = new Intent(this.Activity,typeof(TargetActivity));
StartActivity(intent);